# Named url kwargs in authenticate method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I'm trying to create a custom authentication class in the Django rest framework. In the authenticate(self, request) method, at first glance, it seems that there is no way to get named kwarg from the URL. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just curious, what's the use case? For restrictions based on url, shouldn't that be handled in permissions?

Comment: I'm trying to authenticate a user based on some parts of the URL. In this concrete case, the URL has a form of protocol/domain/<uidb64>/<token> (e.g. activation link, reset password link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get url via `request.get_full_path()`:

```py
def authenticate(self, request):
    ...
    url = request.get_full_path()
```

Check django docs in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend you might find it useful

Comment: Is there a way to get named parameter by name from that URL, or it must be extracted by splitting or regex?